# Jsoup поиск по всем параметрам

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><var class="postImg" title="ertyuio;.,mnbvdjkl"
```

Строка страницы которую я хочу найти.как делать поиск по всем параметрам.

```
doc.select("span[class=post-align]");
doc.select("span[style=text-align: center;]");
```

это поиск по отдельным параметрам.
Суть в том что на страницы много разных строк в которых присутствуют эти параметры, отдельно по классу или id не подходит. мне надо сузить поиск.  Тоесть я хочу включить в поиск class style var одновременно.Найти в данном случае мне надо title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так прямо и ищите, [документация](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) разрешает сочетать селекторы в любом порядке:

```
    String html = "<span class=\"post-align\" style=\"text-align: center;\"><var class=\"postImg\" title=\"ertyuio;.,mnbvdjkl\">first</var></span>"
            + "<span class=\"post-align\" ><var class=\"postImg\" title=\"ertyuio;.,mnbvdjkl\">second</var></span>"
            + "<span style=\"text-align: center;\"><var class=\"postImg\" title=\"ertyuio;.,mnbvdjkl\">third</var></span>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );

    // или "span[style=\"text-align: center;\"][class=post-align] var"
    for( Element element : doc.select( "span.post-align[style=text-align: center;] var" ) ) {
        System.out.println( element.attr( "title" )  );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Действуйте, находя элементы по очереди:

1. Сначала найдите элементы по классу:

   ```
   Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("post-align");
   ```
2. Теперь среди них с нужным стилем:

   ```
   Elements elsWithStyle = new Elements();
   for(Element el:els)
   {
       if(el.attr("style").equals("text-align: center;"))
       {
           elsWithStyle.add(el);
       }
   }
   ```
3. И, наконец, вытаскиваем `title` из `var`:

   ```
   for(Element elWithStyle: elsWithStyle)
   {
       Element var = elWithStyle.children().first();
       String title = var.attr("title");
       Syste.out.println(title);
   }
   ```